# How to disable YouTube “Someone liked your comment” notifications?

Tags: youtube, notifications, comments

I have access to two YouTube accounts. One of them shows notifications on the YouTube website every time someone likes my comments. The other does not. These two accounts seem to have the exact same settings. How do I disable these notifications?

The notifications appear on the bell icon in the upper-right corner of every YouTube webpage. They are worded as “ Someone liked your comment: [content of my comment here]”.

They appear with an ellipsis button that offers two options: 1) “Hide this notification” and 2) “Turn off comment activity”. Neither of those seem applicable.

Otherwise on page https://www.youtube.com/account_notifications I have these settings on both accounts:

[image: Screenshot of Notification Settings Page]